# Disabling drift plugin from homepage

Tags: plugins

So our client wants to use Drift the messaging pop up plugin but it is seriously hindering load speeds on the homepage. I can halve the load time by disabling it but they want to keep it through out the rest of the site, i have tried several plugin organiser plugins but none of them seem to register it, does any one know of any code snippet or know more about how drift works so i can just stop it from loading on a homepage?

Comment: Have you contacted Drift plugin support? 3rd party plugin support is offtopic on this stack

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the plugin embeds the Drift code [by hooking wp_head](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/drift/tags/1.8.4/includes/embed.php):

```
// Add the Drift Javascript
add_action('wp_head', 'add_drift');
```

So all you need to do is

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'add_drift' );
```

when you're on the homepage, e.g. in an `if (is_home())` or `if (is_front_page())` block ([they're more or less equivalent here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/)) in your theme, which will be loaded after the plugins. Or you could even put this at the top of your home page template before you call wp_head().

Comment: That said, the snippet you've got on your homepage generates a script tag with [the 'async' flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async) set, so it shouldn't actually slow down your page load either for automated testers or for users. Are you sure this is your problem?